# Count result according level

Tags: php, mysql

I have Adjacency list mode structure like that and i want to count all title of parent according level like `Food = (2,4,3), Fruit = (3,3)`

tree tabel structure

[image]

after that make tree like that

[image]

by this code i m getting right total like for Food =9, Fruit = 6

```
function display_children($parent, $level) 
{

 $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '.'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'"');
 $count = 0;
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    $data=  str_repeat(' ',$level).$row['title']."\n";
    echo $data;
    $count += 1 + $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1);
   }  
    return $count; 
 }
```

call function

```
 display_children(Food, 0)
```

Result :   9  // but i want to get result like 2,4,3

But i want to get count total result like that For Food 2,4,3 and For Fruit 3,3 according level

so plz guide how to get total according level

Comment: Why only `(2,4,3)`? Why `(9,11)` is left aside? You need the leftmost branch only?

Comment: bcoz i want to Show counting according level

Comment: What you mean by `counting according level`? Please, explain how `(2,4,3)` is different from `(9,11)`? Do you need the branch with the biggest depth from the root maybe?

Comment: Fruit and meat come under Food(so i count 2 in level 1) and Red, Green,Yellow,Pork come under Fruit and meat(so i want to count 4 in level2) like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get amounts by level, then make the function return them by level.

```
function display_children($parent, $level) 
{

 $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree WHERE parent="'.$parent.'"');
 $count = array(0=>0);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    $data=  str_repeat(' ',$level).$row['title']."\n";
    echo $data;
    $count[0]++;
    $children= $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1);
    $index=1;
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
     if ($child==0)
      continue;
     if (isset($count[$index]))
      $count[$index] += $child;
     else    
      $count[$index] = $child;
     $index++;
    }
   }  
    return $count; 
 }
```

Note that its hard for me to debug the code as i dont have your table. If there is any error let me know and i will fix it.
Anyways result will be array 
which should contain amounts of levels specified by indices:

```
$result=display_children("Food", 0) ;
var_export($result);//For exact info on all levels 
echo $result[0];//First level, will output 2
echo $result[1];//Second level, will output 4
echo $result[2];//Third level, will output 3
```

And by the way there is typo in your database, id 10 (Beef) should have parent "Meat" instead of "Beat" i guess.

If you want to see testing page, its [here](http://test.hanzlsoft.eu/stack.php).

Comment: thanks for replay,but it's giving total output in array like that array([]=>9) not level by

Comment: Thats really weird, i made exactly same table in my database and it worked as expected. Maybe there is some php version mismatch that makes the array values work bad, try the fixed code

Answer (score 3):

```
function display_children($parent, $level) 
{

 $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '.'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'"');
 $count = "";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
    $data=  str_repeat(' ',$level).$row['title']."\n";
    echo $data;
    if($count!="")   
        $count .= (1 + $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1));
    else
        $count = ", ".(1 + $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1));
   }  
    return $count; 
 }
```

Lets try this once..

Comment: thanks for replay, but code is not working, not giving counting

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind changing your schema I have an alternative solution which is much simpler.

You have your date in a table like this...

```
item             id
-------------+------
Food         |  1
Fruit        |  1.1
Meat         |  1.2
Red Fruit    |  1.1.1
Green Fruit  |  1.1.2
Yellow Fruit |  1.1.3
Pork         |  1.2.1
```

Queries are now much simpler, because they're just simple string manipulations. This works fine on smallish lists, of a few hundred to a few thousand entries - it may not scale brilliantly - I've not tried that.

But to count how many things there are at the 2nd level you can just do a regexp search.

```
select count(*) from items
where id regexp '^[0-9]+.[0-9]+$'
```

Third level is just

```
select count(*) from items
where id regexp '^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$'
```

If you just want one sub-branch at level 2

```
select count(*) from items
where id regexp '^[0-9]+.[0-9]+$'
and id like "1.%"
```

It has the advantage that you don't need to run as many queries on the database, and as a bonus it's much easier to read the data in the tables and see what's going on.

I have a nagging feeling this might not be considered "good form", but it does work very effectively. I'd be very interested in any critiques of this method, do DB people think this is a good solution? If the table were very large, doing table scans and regexps all the time would get very inefficient - your approach would make better use of the any indexes, which is why I say this probably doesn't scale very well, but given you don't need to run so many queries, it may be a trade off worth taking.

Answer (score 0):

An solution by a php class :

```
<?php

class LevelDepCount{

    private $level_count=array();

    /**
     * Display all child of an element
     * @return int Count of element
     */
    public function display_children($parent, $level, $isStarted=true) 
    {
    if($isStarted)
            $this->level_count=array(); // Reset for new ask
     $result = mysql_query('SELECT title FROM tree '.'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'"');
     $count = 0; // For the level in the section
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {
        $data=  str_repeat(' ',$level).$row['title']."\n";
        echo $data;
        $count += 1 + $this->display_children($row['title'], $level+1,false);
       }
        if(array_key_exists($level, $this->level_count))
            $this->level_count[$level]+=$count;
        else
            $this->level_count[$level]=$count;
            return $count; 
    }

    /** Return the count by level.*/
    public function getCountByLevel(){
        return $this->level_count;
    }

}

$counter=new LevelDepCount();
$counter->display_children("Food",0);
var_dump($counter->getCountByLevel());

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you modify your query you can get all the data in one swoop and without that much calculations (code untested):

```
/* Get all the data in one swoop and arrange it for easy mangling later */
function populate_data() {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS amount, GROUP_CONCAT(title) AS children FROM tree GROUP BY parent');
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       /* Each node has the amount of children and their names */
       $data[$row['parent']] = array($row['children'], int($row['amount']));
    }
    return $data;
}

/* The function that does the whole work */
function get_children_per_level($data, $root) {
    $current_children = array($root);
    $next_children = array();
    $ret = array();

    while(!empty($current_children) && !empty($next_children)) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($current_children as $node) {
            $count += $data[$node][0]; /* add the amount */
            $next_children = array_merge($next_children, explode($data[$node][1])); /* and its children to the queue */
        }
        ret[] = $count;
        $current_children = $next_children;
        $next_children = array();
    }

    return $ret;
}

$data = populate_data();
get_children_per_level($data, 'Food');
```

It shouldn't be difficult to modify the function to make a call per invocation or one call per level to populate the data structure without bringing the whole table into memory. I'd suggest against that if you have deep trees with just a few children as it is a lot more efficient to get all the data in one swoop and calculate it. If you have shallow trees with a lot of children, then it may be worth changing.

It would also be possible to put everything together in a single function, but I'd avoid re-calculating data for repeated calls when they are not needed. A possible solution for this would be to make this a class, use the `populate_data` function as the constructor that stores it as an internal private property and a single method that is the same as `get_children_per_level` without the first parameter as it would get the data off its internal private property.

In any case, I'd also suggest you use the ID column as a "parent" reference instead of other columns. To start with, my code will break if any of the names contains a comma :P. Besides, you may have two different elements with the same name. For example, you could have `Vegetables -> Red -> Pepper` and the `Red` will get slumped together with the Fruit's `Red`.

Another thing to note is that my code will enter an infinite loop if your DB data is not a tree. If there is any cycle in the graph, it will never finish. That bug could be easily solved by keeping a `$visited` array with all the nodes that have already been visited and not pushing them into the `$next_children` array within the loop (probably using `array_diff($data[$node][1], $visited)`.